# Why does the program not enter the loadImage() Method?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

The goal of this little program is to load an .jpg image and display it in a Canvas class extended by JPanel, which is displayed in a JFrame object in the Main class, like so:

## The Main-class

```
<code>

    package imageloader;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    public class ImageLoader {
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            Canvas c = new Canvas();
            Graphics g  = frame.getGraphics();
            Loader load = new Loader();  
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            c.setImage(load.loadImage());
            frame.add(c);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }   
    }




</code>
<h1>The Canvas class</h1>


<code>
     package imageloader;
        import java.awt.Graphics;
        import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
        import javax.swing.JPanel;
        public class Canvas extends JPanel 
        {
            private BufferedImage img = null;
            public Canvas()
            {
                this.setSize(500, 500);
                this.setVisible(true);
            }
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g)
            {
                g.drawLine(0, 0, 250, 250); // just to see if the Canvas is painting, and it does!
                g.drawImage(img, 250, 250, null);
                repaint();
            }
            public void setImage(BufferedImage img)
            {
                this.img = img;
            }
        }

</code>
<h1>The Loading class</h1>

<code>

    package imageloader;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
    public class Loader 
    {
        public BufferedImage loadImage()
        {
            BufferedImage im = null;
            try 
            {
                File f = new File("player.jpg");
                im = ImageIO.read(f.getAbsoluteFile());
                System.out.println("Loaded!"); // this did not apear in my Output-Console in Netbeans
            }
            catch (IOException e) {}
            return im;
        }
    }

</code>
```

My main question is already asked in the title. First I compared the code with the Java Documentation Tutorial and changed the Parent class from Canvas.java to Component with little effect. Look here for reference:

[Link to source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java)

Then I found this with Google:

[Displaying an image in Swing (on StackOverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333802/displaying-an-image-in-java-swing)

Since my JFrame (or component for that matter) did in fact execute the drawLine() function from (0|0) to (250|250) that was not the issue, but I did try out paintcomponent() and paintComponents(), the first drew the line but not the image and seemed considerably slower, the latter did not draw the Line at all, so I switched back to the paint() method again.

Before my little research I tried different things on my own. I changed the Loader class a little up from the Tutorial-Version.

The full tutorial is available here: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html)

Comment: Well you've silently thrown away an IOException, that's never a smart move...

Comment: Are you sure your path for player.jpg is right ?

Comment: Thanks John... I know I could print out that stack... Raghu K Nair, yes I am sure since the picture is in the same folder as my source, so I do not have a long path and work around that possible hazard! I appreciate your Input... plus I changed the code so the Path of the file is found out by the File class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with John3136, but to answer directly:

If you're not seeing "Loaded!", then it's an indication that one of the other two lines in the try is throwing an exception. Troubleshooting further is difficult without the exception information.

Put e.printStackTrace() in your catch block, and post the result here if you're still having difficulty.

Although the file may be in the same directory as your source, it has to be in the same directory as your **executable** for your code to find it. Check the value of f.getAbsolutePath() to see if it's what you're expecting.

Comment: Could you mark this as answered? It simplifies the book-keeping.