# My image doesn't get displayed, why?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an exercise in school where you are meant to change the code so that the image moves. The problem is that the image doesn't show in the first place and I don't know why. Here is the code:

```
public void exercise1e() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("images/gubbe.jpg");
    PaintWindow_GU1.showWindow(600, 400, "P1", Color.WHITE);
    PaintWindow_GU1.addSound("Skor", "sounds/trasiga_skor.mp3");
    PaintWindow_GU1.playSound("Skor");
    int width = PaintWindow_GU1.getBackgroundWidth();
    int height = PaintWindow_GU1.getBackgroundHeight();
    int dx = -2;
    int dy = 1;
    int x = 250;
    int y = rand.nextInt(height-100);  
    PaintWindow_GU1.addIcon("Gubbe", image, 250, y, true);


    while(true) {
        PaintWindow_GU1.setIconXY("Gubbe",x,y);
        PaintWindow_GU1.pause(20); 
        x += dx;
        y += dy;
        if(x<0) {
            dx = -dx;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Java is not JavaScript!

Comment: Your program will never become idle, use a timer instead.

Comment: Try this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333802/displaying-an-image-in-java-swing

Comment: Hint: don't block the EDT (event dispatch thread) - put the loop into a worker/separate thread.

Comment: Is that Swing? This doesn't look like an animation loop. But you will need one for animations. Unless you just want to use a `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: does your console show something? Because maybe your image cant be found, check if you have an image at `images/gubbe.jpg`

Comment: It's not clear what `PaintWindow_GU1` is. Is that a class provided by your school? It seems to do stuff we know nothing about, so it's hard to help you.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to create an images folder in your workspace in order for it to show up  like Ivaro18 explained.

Comment: this should be comment.