# Displaying an Image using Swing in Java

Tags: java, image, swing, jfilechooser

I have been crawling Oracle and Stack Overflow trying to find a solution to my problem, but I haven't managed to find what I am looking for.

Below I have two classes, and all the program needs to do at the moment is allow the user to open an image file using a `JFileChooser` and display it in the GUI (So later some image manipulation can be done to it)

I have tested the code execution to the point that I know the variable `img` in the `ImageGUI` class is being initialized to the picture I want on line 99. My issue is getting the image to show in the GUI before I `pack();` it.

What am I missing?

```
 public class ImageEditLaunch {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ImageEditEngine program = new ImageEditEngine();

}

}

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class ImageEditEngine {

    private static int[][][] originalImage;
    private static BufferedImage originalImageBuffer;

    public ImageEditEngine() {
        originalImage = new int[0][0][0];
        ImageGUI gui = new ImageGUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static ImageIcon openImage(String filepath){
        try{

        File f = new File(filepath);
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(f);
        originalImageBuffer = image;
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
        return icon;

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ImageIcon();
        }

    }
}

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class ImageGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    private JFrame window;

    private JMenuItem mOpenFile;
    private JMenuItem mSaveFile;
    private JMenuItem mExitCommand;

    private JMenuBar parentBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu;
    private JMenu commandMenu;

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public ImageIcon img;

    private JLabel mLabel;

    public ImageGUI(){
        super();
        try{
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //setup CommandMenu
        commandMenu = makeMenu("Command", 'C');

        //setup FileMenu
        fileMenu  = makeMenu("File", 'F');
        mOpenFile     = makeMenuItem(fileMenu, "Open...", 'O');
        mSaveFile     = makeMenuItem(fileMenu, "Save...", 'S');
        mExitCommand  = makeMenuItem(fileMenu, "Exit", 'X');

        //setup parentBar
        parentBar = new JMenuBar();
        parentBar.add(fileMenu);
        parentBar.add(commandMenu);

        //main panel
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mLabel = new JLabel();
        mainPanel.add(mLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setJMenuBar(parentBar);
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

    }

    protected JMenuItem makeMenuItem(JMenu menu, String name, char mnemonic){
        JMenuItem m = new JMenuItem(name, (int) mnemonic);
        m.addActionListener(this);
        menu.add(m);
        return m;
    }

    protected JMenu makeMenu(String name, char mnemonic){
        JMenu menu = new JMenu(name);
        menu.setMnemonic(mnemonic);
        return menu;
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if(arg0.getSource()==mOpenFile){
            String path = null;

            JFileChooser jfc = new JFileChooser();
            jfc.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));

            int result = jfc.showOpenDialog(this);

            if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = jfc.getSelectedFile();
                path = file.getAbsolutePath();
            }

            img=ImageEditEngine.openImage(path);
            mLabel= new JLabel(img);
            mLabel.setVisible(true);
            this.repaint();
            pack();

        }

    }
}
```

The value of the toString() on mLabel right after:

```
mLabel = new JLabel(img);
```

is as follows

```
javax.swing.JLabel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,
border=,flags=8388608,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,
defaultIcon=javax.swing.ImageIcon@2bd58ce,disabledIcon=,
horizontalAlignment=CENTER,horizontalTextPosition=TRAILING,
iconTextGap=4,labelFor=,text=,verticalAlignment=CENTER,
verticalTextPosition=CENTER]
```

Comment: 1) The file chooser returns a `File` so pass that file instead of a `String`. 2) What exactly is the file name and extension that you are trying to open? The JRE will only be able to load particular types of images.

Comment: I will try that now, I am trying to open a jpg file

Comment: *"I am trying to open a jpg file"* JPEG is a 'container format' that might be encoded in any number of ways. Java will be OK with some of them, but not others. Download one of the **Pictures** mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556) and try loading that. They are definitely 'Java compatible'.

Comment: 1) Don't put code or exception output in comments, where it is illegibly. Add it to the question as an [edit], and use code formatting. 2) Reduce the question down to a [mcve], and hot-link to images from that question (i.e. load them by URL), to make it easy for others to test. Note that an MCVE needs a `main(String[])` method to launch it, imports.. basically everything needed to demonstrate the problem with a single copy/paste/compile/run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental problem was that the panel was never added to the frame. There were many other problems with the code, some of which I fixed (by just removing entire sections of it), others that I tweaked. There are still other problems with the code shown below that need to be fixed (one or two of which I introduced just in lazy coding - but they are not fatal).

Having said that, this code now works. Look over it carefully for tips. Note that it is an MCVE that hot links to the image, so it should be easy to test.

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.net.URL;

public class ImageEditEngine {

    private static int[][][] originalImage;
    private static BufferedImage originalImageBuffer;

    public ImageEditEngine() {
        originalImage = new int[0][0][0];
        ImageGUI gui = new ImageGUI();
        gui.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static ImageIcon openImage(){
        try{
            URL url = new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVOg3.jpg");

            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(url);
            originalImageBuffer = image;
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            return icon;

        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new ImageIcon();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ImageEditEngine();
    }
}


class ImageGUI extends JFrame {

    private JPanel mainPanel;

    public ImageIcon img;

    private JLabel mLabel;

    public ImageGUI(){
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        try{
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //main panel
        mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mLabel = new JLabel();
        mainPanel.add(mLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        add(mainPanel);

        setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        img=ImageEditEngine.openImage();
        mLabel.setIcon(img);
        mLabel.setVisible(true);
        this.repaint();
        pack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If I want to display an image on the GUI I embed the image in a JLabel. It works perfectly.

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(IMG_PATH));
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
```

[Displaying an image in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333802/displaying-an-image-in-java-swing)

this should work!

Comment: in my case, it is showing via toString(); that the JLabel is never being initialized, although my code is 'mLabel = new JLabel(img);' where img is an imageicon that I have checked is initialized.

Comment: This answer does not address the core problem in the code in the question.